# Using series find $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^4}\hspace{1mm} dx$ up to $2$ decimal places

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, power-series, approximation

I cannot figure out an aesthetic way to do this.

Can someone give a beautiful solution to this ugly question?

---

This is what I have tried yet.

I used the fact that $$x = \dfrac{1}{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}$$

Hence $$x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^n$$

Now replacing $x$ with $\sqrt{1+x^4}$, to get $$\sqrt{1+x^4} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\right)^n$$

$ $

Just wondering if there are better alternatives available.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: just made an edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint :**

[Maclaurin series for Binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) is
$$
(1+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k} y^n,
$$
for $|y|<1$ and all $n$. Also use identities  binomial coefficients:
$$
\binom{n}{0}=1
$$
and
$$
\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{n}{k}\frac{n-k}{k+1}.
$$
Now, replace $y=x^4$ and then integrate it term by term.

Comment: I see, I was actually doing it without using series. Any substitution can also work here?

Comment: i extremely highly doubt that, you can do by substitution. I will give u a medal, if u can do by substtution

Comment: Its not about medal @user155188 . But, I will try doing that with substitution. Will post my work here.

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Since the OP asked using series, then this answer I provide.

Comment: Yeah @Tunk-Fey , its completely fine. I was just trying to do with different methods. As, doing a problem with alternate methods is always a good practice.

Comment: @tuny-fuk, ur answer sounds good, it works actually,

Comment: @user155188 I tried to substitute x = sin theta, but unfortunately, this doesn't work. Sorry that I couldn't help with this method.

Comment: never mind, i was sure  about that, because i know that its not possible to integrate sqrt(1+x^n) for x > 2

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\root{1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x&=
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n}x^{4n}\,\dd x
=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{4n}\,\dd x
=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n}{1 \over 4n + 1}
\end{align}

> Now we 'cut' the series once the absolute value of the sum 'general term'
>   $\ds{{1/2 \choose n}{1 \over 4n + 1}}$ becomes smaller than $\ds{10^{-2}}$: 
>   $$
> \begin{array}{rclrcl}
> \verts{{1/2 \choose n}{1 \over 4n + 1}}_{\,n\ =\ 0} & = & 1\,,&\qquad
> \verts{{1/2 \choose n}{1 \over 4n + 1}}_{\,n\ =\ 1} & = & 0.1
> \\[3mm]
> \verts{{1/2 \choose n}{1 \over 4n + 1}}_{\,n\ =\ 2} & \approx &-0.0139\,,&\qquad
> \verts{{1/2 \choose n}{1 \over 4n + 1}}_{\,n\ =\ 3} & \approx & 0.0048
> \end{array}
> $$

Then, I'll use three terms $\ds{\pars{~n = 0,1,2}}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}\root{1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x}
&\approx {1/2 \choose 0}\,{1 \over 4\times 0 + 1}
+{1/2 \choose 1}\,{1 \over 4\times 1 + 1} + {1/2 \choose 2}\,{1 \over 4\times 2 + 1}
\\[3mm]&=1 + 0.1 - 0.0139 = \color{#66f}{\large 1.08\color{#c00000}{61}} 
\end{align}

> A numerical calculation of the integral yields
>   $\ds{\approx \color{#66f}{\large 1.08}9429413}$.

Comment: I think you mean 'becomes smaller than $10^{-2}$'; certainly the value at $n=3$ isn't smaller than $10^{-3}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry. It's $\large 10^{-2}$. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Also, to be a bit more mathematically nitpicky (and this is a fine answer otherwise): don't you really need bounds on the tail and not _just_ the next term?  Otherwise, you have no guarantees that this isn't akin to summing $\sum_n\frac1n$ to 2 places by just going to $n=101$...